# <span> element refuses to go inline in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `span` (`.time-pretext`) inside a `div` inside a flexbox `a`, like this:

```
<a class="option-container option-edit-time" href="#">
  <div class="option-icon"><canvas id="time-canvas" width="128" height="128"></canvas></div>
  <div class="option-text"><span class="time-pretext">I have</span>60 minutes</div>
</a>
```

`.option-text` here gets `flex-direction: column`, and when I give it that property, the span will only take block display options (`block` or `-webkit-box`) and no inline ones (`inline-block`). Why?

Incidentally, it works fine in the original flexbox implementation (`display: -webkit-box`). Only in the newest implementation (`display: flex`) does this come up.

Comment: could you give us a fiddle?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm assuming that your `.option-text` has `display:flex` (otherwise setting `flex-direction` on it would make no sense). Given that, the behavior you describe is actually required by the flexbox spec -- children of a flex container are forced to have a block-flavored display type.

Specifically, the spec says:

> each child of a flex container becomes a flex item [...] The computed ‘display’ of a flex item is determined by applying the table in [CSS 2.1 Chapter 9.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-items

That table it refers to, from CSS 2.1, basically converts non-blocks to blocks.

If you don't want this behavior, just wrap your `<span>` in a `<div>`, and then the `<div>` will play the role of the flex item so that the `<span>` can keep its display type.

Comment: (Note that it's actually the `display: flex` that triggers the display-conversion-to-block for the children -- *not* the `flex-direction: column`, as implied in the original question. I'm guessing `flex-direction: column` just changed the rendering in other ways to just make the span's imposed block display-type more obvious.)

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by @dholbert is naturally correct. However, there is another solution that worked for me for the browsers Chrome, Edge, and Firefox. You have to set the `display` CSS attribute to `contents`.

In your case, it is:

```css
span.time-pretext {
    display: contents;
}
```

Or for a more general solution:

CSS:

```css
span.flex-inline {
    display: contents;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<a class="option-container option-edit-time" href="#">
  <div class="option-icon"><canvas id="time-canvas" width="128" height="128"></canvas></div>
  <div class="option-text"><span class="flex-inline time-pretext">I have</span>60 minutes</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Using `display: contents` is an elegant approach and this answer deserves more recognition. For more on `display: contents`, read Rachel Andrew's posts on [*Vanishing boxes with display contents*](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/01/29/vanishing-boxes-with-display-contents/) and [*Why display: contents is not CSS Grid Layout subgrid*](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/07/20/why-display-contents-is-not-css-grid-layout-subgrid/)

Comment: This is a much better solution!!! +1